# Can a non-retina MacBook's screen be replaced with a Retina screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm using a MacBook Pro Late 2011. The processor, RAM, hard drive - just about everything else still work fine. I'd like to have retina display without necessarily buying a new unit.

Is there a way to change my screen to a retina display - i.e. physically removing the old screen and replacing it with a retina one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work. This [iFixit answer](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/107210/Possible+to+install+a+Retina+Display+on+an+Early+2011+unibody+MacBook) outlines the various issues:

> Unfortunately, the simple answer is no. The graphics card would have issues running the display if you were even able to install it. The Retina display MacBook Pro also has different connectors and dimensions then the regular Macbook Pro and therefore not fit and not connect. The firmware for you computer will also not scale the resolution and render properly so you would have a 1440 x 900 resolution displaying on a 2880 x 1800 display which would only take up 1/4 of the display.

As the answerer says, your biggest problem is the graphics card. The mobile card on your Late 2011 MacBook Pro just isn't designed to push quadruple the pixels at an acceptable framerate.

Comment: Perhaps not internally, but it can drive a retina display according to Apple: 
Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors

Answer (score 3):

Not easily. The Retina MacBook Pro introduced a new display assembly which makes retro-fitting very difficult.

> Rather than sandwich an LCD panel between a back case and a piece of glass in front, Apple used the aluminium case itself as the frame for the LCD panel and used the LCD as the front glass

<sup>Source: http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+Retina+Display+Teardown/9493</sup>

The cost of doing so would probably be more than the rMBP itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since Apple computers hold their value so well, you might be able to sell your existing Mac and buy a new one for less than the difference in part cost and have two fully supported Macs in service - the one you sold and the one you now have.

Doing any sort of DIY customization is always possible with enough budget and experience, but even if you were to get the display panel connected the old CPU/GPU will likely be very underpowered or balk at running the new display without extensive firmware modifications or tweaks.

Answer (score -1):

You can change it to a Hi-Res (but not Retina) display from Apple, I think, but it is only for the 15 inch model

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: His answer is sufficient. why waffle?

Answer (score -2):

actually i think you can, as I bought the wrong display to my 15" macbook pro 2009, i bought on ebay a macbook pro display of late 2012/early 2013 and these are retina display! It worked fine but i had to re-sale it as the video conectors are the same but not the wifi/bluetooth/camera connectors, and the screw of the hinge are placed differentley but it still holds minus 1 screw! For the resolution i havn't tried to configure it to retina resolution to see if it could work, I suppose it was working at the native resolution of what my macbook could offer, but it was working fine!

Answer (score -4):

i did by bringing to a tech fix store near me, and i assume it could be done to yours if the computer would support it.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain a thing that how do someone will be able to replace the screen to Retina.