# Can i use A1278 screen to replace with my A1502 screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I've a A1502 macbook pro late 2013 with damaged 13" retina display. There is another A1278 macbook pro with 13" display. I am getting this laptop way cheaper than the screen replacement. I was wondering if i could use an A1278 screen to replace with my A1502 screen. Is it possible? Are there any hardware differences? Maybe difference in the wire connector on board? Or any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered for 'the other way round': [putting a Retina screen in an older MBP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115638/can-a-non-retina-macbooks-screen-be-replaced-with-a-retina-screen), and I'd suggest many of the answers there apply here.

The screens are different dimensions, and use different connectors. The firmware expects the original screen resolution.